# Prove if the following is true or provide a counterexample if it is not

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

For all sets A and B, |P(A × B)| $\ne$ |P(A) × P(B)|
My first instinct is that it is false and I picked sets like A = {1}, B = {2} but when you write out the power set of these sets you end up with P(A) = {{1},{empty}} and P(B) = {{2},{empty}}. Now taking their cartesian product (on the right hand side) results in empty sets and I don't know if taking the cartesian product of an empty set is even allowed. The left hand side looks like this if it's any help. P(A x B) ={{1,2},0} and I'm trying to show that both the left hand side and right hand side are equal. Am i going about this the right way?

Comment: Yes, but as you pointed out, you have to drill done on the cartesian product with empty set(s).

Answer (score 1):

Two theorems:

$|A\times B|=|A||B|$

$|P(A)|=2^{|A|}$

So $$|P(A\times B)|=2^{|A\times B|}=2^{|A||B|}$$ and
$$|P(A)\times P(B)|=|P(A)||P(B)|=2^{|A|}2^{|B|}$$

So if $|A|+|B|\not=|A||B|$, they're not the same.

Comment: It's worth noting that so long as one of $A$ and $B$ are infinite, $|A|+|B|=|A||B|$ will hold true.  For the finite case, we can consider the following question: for what natural numbers $a,b$ can we have $a+b=ab$?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach and example work if you carry through correctly. First, $A=\{1\}$, so $\wp(A)=\big\{\varnothing,\{1\}\big\}$, not $\big\{\{\varnothing\},\{1\}\big\}$. The subsets of $A$ are $A$ itself (i.e., $\{1\}$) and $\varnothing$; $\{\varnothing\}$ is not a subset of $A$. If it were, $\varnothing$ would be an *element* of $A$, and it’s not: the only element of $A$ is $1$. Similarly, $\wp(B)=\big\{\varnothing,\{2\}\big\}$. Thus

$$\begin{align*}
\wp(A)\times\wp(B)&=\{\langle a,b\rangle:a\in\wp(A)\text{ and }b\in\wp(B)\}\\
&=\big\{\langle\varnothing,\varnothing\rangle,\langle\varnothing,\{2\}\rangle,\langle\{1\},\varnothing\rangle,\langle\{1\},\{2\}\rangle\big\}\;;
\end{align*}$$

note that it has four elements.

Now

$$\begin{align*}
A\times B&=\{1\}\times\{2\}\\
&=\{\langle a,b\rangle:a\in A\text{ and }b\in B\}\\
&=\{\langle 1,2\rangle\}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$\begin{align*}
\wp(A\times B)&=\wp(\{\langle 1,2\rangle\})\\
&=\big\{\varnothing,\{\langle 1,2\rangle\}\big\}\;:
\end{align*}$$

the only element of $A\times B$ is the ordered pair $\langle 1,2\rangle$, so the only subsets of $A\times B$ are the empty set and $A\times B$ itself, just as the only subsets of $A$ are $\varnothing$ and $A$ itself. Thus, $\wp(A\times B)$ has only $2$ elements and therefore cannot be equal to the $4$-element set $\wp(A)\times\wp(B)$.

You should also notice that $\wp(A\times B)$ and $\wp(A)\times\wp(B)$ have different *kinds* of elements: elements of $\wp(A\times B)$ are sets of ordered pairs, while elements of $\wp(A)\times\wp(B)$ are ordered pairs of sets.